# Write binary integer byte to a serial connection with GO

Tags: binary, serial-port, go

Does this write a `4` (the byte `00000100`) to the serial port?

```
buf := make([]byte, 4)
d, err := connection.Write(buf)
```

Because it seems like *something* is getting sent, but my code on the other end that is expecting a 4 does not get triggered.  I have other code in another language that sends a 4 to the Arduino, and it responds fine.  And I can see the light blink when the above code runs, but it's somehow not he byte I'm expecting.

So how do send the byte `00000100` over the serial port?

Full code here:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/tarm/goserial"
  "log"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  config := &serial.Config{Name: "/dev/tty.usbmodem1421", Baud: 9600}
  connection, err := serial.OpenPort(config)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  // Wait for Arduino
  time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

  // Send the binary integer 4 to the serial port
  buf := make([]byte, 4)
  _, err = connection.Write(buf)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  // Wait for Arduino
  time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

  // Cleanup
  connection.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I totally misunderstood the second argument to `make`...

```
buf := make([]byte, 1) // second arg is lenght of array, not a value in the array
binary.PutUvarint(buf, 8) // add my int value to the buffer
connection.Write(buf) // send it!
```

Comment: It's very unlikely you want varint. Just `Write([]byte{4})`

Comment: Which appears not to work as soon as I make `8` an `int` variable instead :(

Comment: `eight := 8`; `Write([]byte{byte(eight)})`